# NSDate and NSDateFormatting and unix timestamp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have the following code:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.firstUsed];
 NSLog(@"FIRST USED %@ %f", dateString, [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.firstUsed]);

FIRST USED 06/15/2012 10:42PM 716.087895
```

The thing that confuse me is that when I put in 173.755023 it doesn't translate back to June 15th 2012 10:42. How is this possible? I think the correct number should be 1339714440

Comment: plz mention what you exactly want to do. you want this date "June 15th 2012 10:42" from timestamp or from timestamp to date. the timestamp you given is wrong for the date.

Comment: and that is exactly the question, why is it wrong? basically the date is correct, but the timestamp is no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSDate* referenceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: 0];
NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
int offset = [timeZone secondsFromGMTForDate: referenceDate];
int unix_timestamp =  [curdate timeIntervalSince1970];
int Timestamp = unix_timestamp - offset;
```

Answer (score -2):

Please write down Following Code :

```
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatAppointment = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dtFormatAppointment setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.firstUsed];

NSTimeInterval time = [dateString timeIntervalSince1970];

NSLog(@"FIRST USED %@ %.f", dateString, time);
```

this code is working for you.